# GOHeat - x axis labels (gene names) don't show on the plot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, label

I'm trying to plot my Gene Ontology data with GOplot package, specifically GOHeat() function. Unfortunately there's problem with display of gene names - x axis label on plot. Here's visualization of problem:

plot from vignette that's how it should look like:
[image]

and here's how it looks like when I plot it:

[image]

I decided to take a closer look on GOHeat() function and it's preety simple, whole function is [here](https://github.com/cran/GOplot/blob/master/R/GOHeat.R) however I tried to modify ggplot():

```
  g <- ggplot() + 
    geom_tile(data = df_o, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = z))+
    scale_x_discrete(breaks = 1:length(unique(df_o$x)), labels = unique(df_o$lab)) +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5), axis.title.x=element_blank(), axis.title.y=element_blank(),
          axis.text.y = element_text(size = 14), panel.background=element_blank(), panel.grid.major=element_blank(),
          panel.grid.minor=element_blank())
```

I think that the marigins in `axis.text.x = element_text(...)` but my efforts didn't change the plot at all, or even ome errors occured.

To make things easier I show how data looks like:

```
> head(unique(df_o$x))
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6
> head(unique(df_o$lab))
[1] TGFBR3  NRP2    GNA13   SLC22A5 APOE    LEPR   
37 Levels: ACVRL1 AMOT APOE ATP6V0A1 CAV1 CDH2 CDH5 CERKL CXCR4 ECSCR     EFNB2 FGF2 ... VANGL2
```

I'll be very grateful for any clue how to 'turn on' x axis labels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a fixed function:

```
GOHeat_fix <- function (data, nlfc, fill.col) 
{
  x <- y <- z <- NULL
  if (missing(nlfc)) 
    nlfc <- 0
  else nlfc <- nlfc
  if (missing(fill.col)) 
    fill.col <- c("firebrick", "white", "dodgerblue")
  else fill.col <- fill.col
  distance <- dist(data)
  cluster <- hclust(distance)
  M <- dim(data)[2]
  nterm <- M - nlfc
  if (nlfc == 0) {
    s <- rowSums(data[, 1:nterm])
    tmp <- NULL
    for (r in 1:nrow(data)) {
      tmp <- c(tmp, as.numeric(gsub(1, s[r], data[r, 1:nterm])))
    }
  }
  else {
    tmp <- NULL
    for (r in 1:nrow(data)) {
      tmp <- c(tmp, as.numeric(gsub(1, data[r, (nterm + 
                                                  1)], data[r, 1:nterm])))
    }
  }
  df <- data.frame(x = factor(rep(cluster$order, each = nterm)), y = rep(colnames(data[, 
                                                                               1:nterm]), length(rownames(data))), z = tmp, lab = rep(rownames(data), 
                                                                                                                                      each = nterm))
  df_o <- df[order(df$x), ]
  g <- ggplot() +
    geom_tile(data = df_o, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = z)) +
    scale_x_discrete(breaks = 1:length(unique(df_o$x)), labels = unique(df_o$lab)) +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1),
          axis.title.x = element_blank(),
          axis.title.y = element_blank(), 
          axis.text.y = element_text(size = 14),
          panel.background = element_blank(), 
          panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
          panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +
    coord_fixed()
  if (nlfc == 0) {
    g + scale_fill_gradient2("Count", space = "Lab", low = fill.col[2], 
                             mid = fill.col[3], high = fill.col[1])
  }
  else {
    g + scale_fill_gradient2("logFC", space = "Lab", low = fill.col[3], 
                             mid = fill.col[2], high = fill.col[1])
  }
}
```

example:

```
library(GOplot)
data(EC)
circ <- circle_dat(EC$david, EC$genelist)
chord <- chord_dat(data = circ, genes = EC$genes, process = EC$process)
GOHeat_fix(chord[,-8], nlfc = 0)
```

[image]

I fixed the problem with labels and added `coord_fixed()` since that's how heatmaps are usually made.

Comment: Sorry your nice solution returns a heatmap with gene names but for me that I have 200 genes on x axis heatmap very small and non clear. How I can make labels on x and y clear and readable?

Comment: @Feresh Teh The only way I can think of is to make a very large heat-map. Export it to a big pdf.

Comment: Thank you, sorry how can I change your code so that genes are column and GO terms in rows?

Comment: @Feresh Teh try to change the `geom_tile` line to  `geom_tile(data = df_o, aes(x = y, y = x, fill = z))`

Comment: Thank you, I changed the function as you kindly suggested by output is too weird no x and y labels. This is the link of image https://ibb.co/fdSgLtY

Comment: @Feresh Teh also change the line :`scale_x_discrete(breaks = 1:length(unique(df_o$x)), labels = unique(df_o$lab))` to `scale_y_discrete....` If it does not solve your issue please post a new question with a reproducible example.